# Parse.com: How to edit an Array

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

There's something troubling me for a few days now: 
I have an Object called House, inside this object I have an Array with pointers to my Rooms.

Let's say that I want to remove a room from the house.

I can do it manually: Go to the the data Browser, remove the room from his "table" and edit the array removing the entry.

And I can do it from code: remove the room from the House.Rooms list and commit to parse.

The problem is, after I deleted this room and I try to get the House with a include=rooms, Parse won't return the rooms. I will return just the array codes.

Note that before delete the room, all worked fine.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
Room : ParseObject
...
House : ParseObject
...

var rooms = new List<Room>();
rooms.Add(Kitchen);
rooms.Add(BathRoom);
rooms.Add(BedRoom);
rooms.Add(BedRoomCouple);

ParseObject house = new House;
house.Rooms = rooms;
await house.SaveAsync();

await fullHouseFromParse = ParseQuery<House>().Include("rooms").FindAsync();

// House.Rooms will be filled with all data.
// For example, House.Rooms[0].Name will be filled 

Now, try to delete some rooms:

...
await houseFromParse = ParseQuery<House>().Include("rooms").FindAsync();
await rooms = ParseQuery<Room>().FindAsync();
rooms.Add(Kitchen);
rooms.Add(BathRoom);
rooms.Add(BedRoom);
rooms.Add(BedRoomCouple);

rooms.Remove(0,1)
await rooms.SaveAsync();

houseFromParse.Rooms = rooms;
await house.SaveAsync();

await fullHouseFromParse = ParseQuery<House>().Include("rooms").FindAsync();
// here the house won't have the rooms.
```

Even if you go to Parse.com Web Api and try to get the rooms, all it will return is

```
{
    "ACL": {
        "role:5x6u4LxXlV_cad": {
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        }
    },
    "createdAt": "2015-12-17T17:47:51.021Z",
    "description": "House",
    "name": "House",
    "objectId": "[someId]",
    "owner": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": "[someId]"
    },
    "rooms": [
        {
            "objectId": "bTLjAWAufj"
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt": "2015-12-21T13:56:57.429Z"
}
```

Comment: Don't you think this is offtopic for SO and instead should be asked to Parse.com community/support people?

Comment: Do you have some sample code, so we can see what is happening?

Comment: Hi @cFrozenDeath. No, I don't think that's an off topic, from Parse.com support page: "Need technical support?
Lots of users and members of the Parse team are active on Stack Overflow."

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I added a few lines of code, hope it helps to clarify my question :)